# java convert long time to java.util.Date

Tags: java

why this is different:
 `select from_unixtime(1383699655)`,  I get `'2013-11-06 09:00:55'`, but when I convert 1383699655 to
`java.util.Date,new Date(1383699655)`, I get the  `Sat Jan 17 08:21:43 CST 1970`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The unix timestamp is in seconds and java `Date` needs milliseconds.

Thus you must convert

```
 new Date(1383699655 * 1000L)
```

Answer (score 3):

Java time is milliseconds passed Jan 01 1970 00:00. Unix time is seconds. Multiply by 1000.